# How can I generate a matching matrix/array in numpy/scipy/pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I need a boolean array that indicates whether an item in a list/Series matches each other item in the same array. This is probably a single scipy function if I knew what to call it, but my searches haven't been fruitful. The following code does what I need, but would likely benefit from being vectorized.

```
import numpy as np

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'yellow']
match_array = np.ndarray((len(colors), len(colors)), dtype=bool)

for i, y in enumerate(colors):
    for j, x in enumerate(colors):
        match_array[i][j] = (x == y)

print(match_array)
```

Output:

```
[[ True False False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False False]
 [ True False False  True  True False]
 [ True False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False  True]]
```

It is symmetrical about the diagonal, as expected, and matches the 'red' at index 0 with the other 'red's at indices 3 and 4 across both axes. Is there a library function available to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert your categories to indices or something numerical, broadcasting does everything for you

```
c_num = np.array([0,1,2,0,0,3])  # mimic colors
match_array = c_num[:,None] == c_num
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: A string-dtyped array will do exactly that, so just `np.array(colors)`.